# What is the protocoll used nodes in a p2p connection?

Tags: nodeos

I am trying to understand how nodes communicate but I haven't found any information about this. Is NodeOS opensource?

I am also quite new in EOSIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p2p protocol is TCP based, but not a standard protocol like HTTP.

It is open source: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos